# How to get submitted form to rendered format to email?

Tags: safecracker, email, entry

Let's say I have a form from channel "contact_us" and it is submitted through template "index/contactus". How can I use the "channel_form_submit_entry_end" hook to collect the data and template put it together and have it ready to be sent for an email? Running EE5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else is looking for the answer:
If after your extension is called you can rebuild the template using the following code

```
function your_function($obj){
$template_group = "template_group_name"; \\(string)
$template = "template_name"; \\(string)
ee()->uri->page_query_string = $obj->entry('entry_id');\\assign your own entry_id (int)
ee()->load->library('template', NULL, 'TMPL');
ee()->TMPL->fetch_and_parse($template_group, $template, FALSE);
$rendered = ee()->TMPL->parse_globals(ee()->TMPL->final_template);
echo $rendered;
}
```

Of course you can display it or set values how ever you want.